# PHP 500 SERVER ERROR - DevTools failed to load source map: Could not load content for chrome-extension (ERR_BLOCKED_BY_CLIENT)

Tags: php, google-chrome, brave

Language used : PHP

I've got "PHP 500 SERVER ERROR - DevTools failed to load source map: Could not load content for chrome-extension (ERR_BLOCKED_BY_CLIENT)" when I post a form.

Sometimes it is working, and I don't have any error, sometimes it is not.

When it's not working, if I uncheck "Enable css/js source maps", it does not work either.

I'm searching where the error can came from, but i really don't know.

I was thinking that, it's maybe a typo error (like, when I copy/paste the text instead of writing it, or when I have special characters... but I'm not sure because sometimes it's work even with that).

Today, it was not working on firefox, but then I have tried on "brave" and check 'Allow DevTools to load ressources, such as source maps, from remote file paths. Disabled by default for security reasons' and it worked..

If someone has an idea.

Comment: You can enable/disable source maps in devtool settings, I would check that the path it is trying to load the sourcemap from actually exists, if it doesn't, generate them... or simply just ignore this error

Answer (score 0):

This could be caused by Adblock or a similar type of browser extension, try disabling the extension and see if you still are getting the error in Dev tools.

Comment: Hello. Well, i don't have any extension so I don't think it is because of that. It seems to happened only when i copy/past in my input some text instead of writing it . Thank you for your answer